# Handling skip in rpart and random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a dataset containing 10 categorical variables. Each of these has missing values coded as (-9, -6, -3, -2, -1). I want to create 1 column that takes the mean of these 10 variables excluding the negative values. I can collapse the negative values into NA and then median impute them but I need to retain -6 since -6 implies that the person skipped the question because it does not apply to them. For instance, parental relationship quality does not apply to single parents. I ultimately want to use this variable as a predictor in my random forest model so I am not sure how to handle -6 in this case. One way that I could think of is to impute each of the 10 variables as follows (Let's say that the 10 variables are a1 to a10):

```r
missing_categs <- c(-9, -3, -2, -1)

df[df$a1%in%missing_categs,]$a1 <- assign median value of a1
```

After the above step, I calculate the average of a1 to a10. The ones that yield "-6" are the ones that pertain to single parents (which means it does not apply to them). then, I convert -6 to NA. So, now I have average values and one NA. Can rpart and random forest models handle NA? Other better alternative solutions are most welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Can rpart and random forest models handle NA?

I do not know what you mean with *handle*. If you mean that you can use `NA` in the predictors than the answer is *yes* for `rpart`

```r
> library(rpart)
> df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, NA), c(4, 5, 6))
> rpart(df, na.action=na.pass)
n= 3 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node
```

but *no* for `randomForest`

```r
> library(randomForest)
randomForest 4.6-14
Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.
> df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, NA), c(4, 5, 6))
> randomForest(df, na.action=na.pass)
Error in randomForest.default(df, na.action = na.pass) : 
  NA not permitted in predictors
```

If you mean *handle* that they are able to *deal with them* in *some* manner, for example by giving them a function, than the answer is **yes for both**.

`rpart` and `randomForest` have the parameter `na.action` which you can use. See [here for `rpart`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-15/topics/rpart) and [here for `randomForest`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/randomForest).

The default for `rpart` `na.action` is `na.rpart` which deletes *"all observations for which y is missing"* and *"those in which one or more predictors are missing"* are kept.

The default for `randomForest` `na.action` is [`na.fail`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/na.fail) which returns the given data structure unaltered if no `NA`'s are found, and if at least one `NA` is found it *"signals an error"*.